# Trial version grace period

Tags: trial, trialware, shareware

How should I implement a full-featured grace period or N-uses scheme to maximise sales of my small $5 social network Windows application, while encouraging continued use of a limited version by users who are never (not yet?) going to pay for it?

### Grace-period options:

1. Use-limited. After 20 uses, cripple it.
2. Calendar days time-limited. After 30 days after first-use, the software is crippled.
3. Actual use-days time-limited, eg. 7 days. If used for seven days over the course of 7+N days, cripple it after the seventh day.
4. Time-limited. After 20 hours of use or play, cripple it.
5. Combination of the above with progressive crippling and optional nag screens.
6. Nag screens, which I am averse to.

Crippling software is not favoured by all (especially the open-source camp), but I have to base my decision on happy users and making a living, so I have compiled the findings I side with on limiting software below.

### My trialware conclusions so far:

- Focus on making your software **good** rather than spending time on thwarting crackers. If it is popular enough, it will eventually be reverse engineered.
- Let the client enjoy the **full functionality** of your software...for a while. Dependent users are more likely to buy.
- **Crippled software** can sell [5 times more](http://hackvan.com/pub/stig/articles/why-do-people-register-shareware.html) than software with donation nag screens, assuming it is any good.
- Make paying as easy as humanly possible.
- Perceived value counts, but keeping the [price low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550556/ive-found-my-software-as-cracked-download-on-internet-what-to-do/3553971#3553971) may lead to impulse buys.
- Pricing is *[really hard](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/CamelsandRubberDuckies.html)*.
- Offering a 100% no-questions-asked money-back guarantee will lead to more sales.

I intend to cripple my demo version, but I do want trial users to experience all the features. It's a smallish consumer application with a potentially large user base, so I'm looking at pricing it at **~$5**, but I don't know. It may be worth $50 to some users or $1. I'll leave pricing for later. This is about crippling software.

An answer supported by [real-world data](http://successfulsoftware.net/2009/04/23/the-truth-about-conversion-ratios-for-software/) grouped by [software type](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FiveWorlds.html) would be more helpful, but any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Comment: Everyone's answer so far has been helpful! I've incorporated your feedback into my list of conclusions.

Comment: I added a bounty. Even though I received some good answers, I am still interested in some real world data (like trial version experiments, research or questionnaires) on this subject with a focus on shrink-wrapped software.

Comment: Shrink-wrap software?  Really?  I buy software all the time but I can't remember the last time I bought something shrink-wrapped.  Chris and I have been running our respective software businesses for over a decade.  I won't post real-world data, but my answer is based on real-world experience.

Comment: @Jan, see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FiveWorlds.html for what is meant by "shrink-wrap software".

Comment: @FreshCode - with all due respect to Joel, I don't think that's a widely-accepted description of "shrink-wrap software".

Comment: @Chris, what is the widely-accepted description? Consumer software?

Comment: I've never thought of my products as shrink-wrap software nor have I ever heard anybody call them that.  I guess with the term "shareware" being out of fashion, there isn't a good one-word term for end-user desktop applications.  I just call it "software".

Comment: @Chris & @Jan, Pete Goodliffe refers to "shrink-wrap software" on page 443 of *Code Craft* as "software {...} developed for the **mass market**. It’s used by a large number of people, or at least that’s what the marketing departments are praying for."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is an app that will be used for a long time, go with 30 days non-nag (show "trial" in the titlebar and AboutBox, etc., but nothing that needs clicking), then nag for 7 days, then use an escalated crippling.  Maybe some watermarking of the output.  You probably do not need to fully disable the app.  In order for the purchase/abandon decision to tip in your favor, you need to provide high-quality software, and you need to get the user "invested" before they get to that point.  By "invested", I mean a combination of time, data, comfort, reliance, emotional attachment, etc..
Note that this strategy won't work well for one-off apps (like business card designers) and games (they can just pick up another game and learn to like it).
But for any sort of business app, productivity tool, etc., it will work.

BTW, your observation about the low price wouldn't be true with business-oriented apps or "professional-level" utilities.  If it seems low-priced, people will balk.  Just today, I bought a HDMI-DVI cable on Amazon (3rd-party vendor) for 30 cents. I kept looking for the "gotcha".  Shipping was 3 bucks.  So I bit, as I was buying a nice Tent anyway.  But I really don't have high hopes for this cable. It sounds weird, but I would have been more comfortable paying $12.50.

Comment: +1 on bringing up perceived value and progressive crippling.  Big distinction between once-off apps and regular use. My application seems to fall somewhere in the middle since it is likely to be used in bursts of a few hours or a few days at a time, with multiple bursts over the course of the year. I have no test data on this, but the nature of my app would suggest it. Should I be patient and wait for the user to re-use my app 40 days later (crippled by then) to buy or capitalise on the first burst of usage, eg. 7 days? Hence, long-term vs short-term cripple.

Comment: @Chris, added perceived value to my question.

Comment: @Chris, please edit your answer in some way so I can upvote it. For some reason it's locked for me unless edited.

Comment: @FreshCode. Done. Weird.  UPS says cable has shipped, hope it works!

Comment: Awarded bounty for the importance of getting the user invested, non-nag, perceived value and progressive crippling.

Comment: Update: 30 cent cable turned out to be great! I'm using it now...

Answer (score 5):

My preferred method of limiting trial versions is through **watermarking**.  This method works great for software that is used to produce content.  E.g. my own [HelpScribble](http://www.helpscribble.com) and [DeployMaster](http://www.deploymaster.com) are used to produce help files and installers.  The trial versions of these products create help files and installers without any restriction in time or functionality.  But the output is watermarked.  The help files have a little notice at the bottom of each topic and the installers have an extra box with a notice above the installer's window.  The notices are polite messages that indicate that unpaid software was used, making the help files and installers created by the trials unsalable..  This allows people to try the software without any restrictions.  Payment is only due when they want to distribute the help files or installers.

This approach obviously doesn't work for all applications.  When watermarking is impossible, I tend to go with a time limit based on number of days of actual use.  I never limit trials based on calendar days.  I don't want somebody to install the trial, go on vacation, and come back to an expired trial.

At the end of the day, the best way to limit a trial depends on your product and your market.  My own experience is with tools for programmers and other IT professionals.  Somebody who makes games will likely give a very different answer (e.g. limit the trial to the first few levels or worlds of the game).

And don't forget the **money-back guarantee**!  For me, that's the ultimate trial.  When shopping for software I'll buy without trying if there's a money-back guarantee, particularly if the software was previously recommended to me.  I don't have a lot of time to mess around with trial versions of various applications, particularly for low-cost utilities.

Comment: +1 for 100% no questions asked money-back guarantee and go with actual use day limit. Added it to list of conclusions.

Comment: Watermarking is a great strategy for many apps.

Comment: @FreshCode: If you want to +1 our answers, just click the upward pointing arrow to the upper left of our answers.  You can upvote as many answers as you find useful.

Comment: Please edit your answer in some way so I can upvote it. For some reason it's locked for me unless it is edited.

Comment: @FreshCode: I corrected a typo in my answer.  Normally the stackoverflow system allows answers to be upvoted no matter how old the answer is, but the vote becomes locked after a few minutes until the answer is edited.

Comment: @Jan, I probably up- then down-voted your question initially to keep the question "Unanswered", which caused the lock.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the big boys:

Autodesk offers all its Applications (AutoCAD, Revit and their friends) with a 30-day full-featured trial period. When this period expires, printing and exporting data get disabled.

Intel uses a similar scheme for their Parallel Inspector suite.

This period should give a potential customer enough time to get to like the application - and personally, I have (had) bought programms I tried out in this way, but never to get rid of nagboxes - which shows i am like the majority of people according to your link.

Comment: Autodesk and Parallel Inspector are enterprise software. The sales model for these types of software may be different from a consumer application, but I agree that a 30-day full-featured trial is fairly standard and one would think that big boys have done their homework on this.

Comment: The key concept here is to **limit the business use** of the software, without crippling its apparent functional use, i.e. you can still design things in Autodesk, but you cannot print it for construction or profit.

Answer (score 2):

I would go against nagging entirely, you don't intentionally piss off your potential customers. Most of the time I would close down nag screens and not care until I reach the last day of the trial and then I would make my decision. I wouldn't cripple either. People are emotional before logical. People would sooner go in search of some other app than pay up. People are entitled, generation of critics and relentlessly demanding. I have a few ideas:

Give them X amount of days and then at the end thank them for using your app. If they don't last the trial they're not going to buy it or are really unlikely too.  At the end, give them the price with a little extra on that you would donate to charity if they buy your stuff. Advertise that your customers are awesome because now X has a home to live in, or food or Y just beat cancer. Everyone wants to feel like the belong to something as well as accomplished something. Remind your users that people like them cause miracles to happen.

You could compartmentalise your app and allow people to buy whatever services suit them personally, sometimes 3 dollars is better than no dollars. People are very, very picky so allowing them to build their own version of the app creates a greater sense of control on the part of the user. They'll remember that over someone who just shoved an app in their face and demanded money or nagged them to the point of psychosis-inducing rage.

You could have a small subscription fee e.g. 1 dollar a month.

You could have a pay to play sort of thing where 1 dollar buys you 72 hours.

It's 4am here in ireland so I'm gonig to bed. Let me know if you want to know more.

Comment: +1 for "users who finish the trial are more likely to buy", though I haven't seen data to support a clear correlation and the converse (that those who don't finish won't buy) is definitely not a certainty. Instead of the charity route, which to me feels contrived unless I truly am charitable, I would focus on how the customer is supporting the little guy. Compartmentalising the sale of the app can be good, but it has to be simple enough so Joe from Accounting can understand it. A subscription fee would work well for SaaS, but not for once-off or semi-seasonal use.

Comment: Nagging can be easily disguised as tips/help early on. Mine starts out with "have you tried feature x yet?  It can do xxx for you."  IMO it's important to consistently show a nag so that he user doesn't think it's freeware, and that you're pulling a bait 'n' switch later.  They really want to believe that everything is free, and will talk themselves into believing that it's free, or that they already paid, or that you magically charged their credit card when they downloaded, unless you remind them daily that you are ready to happily process their order in exchange for continued use of the app.

Comment: @Chris All it takes it a trial version message at the top with a counter with how many days are left. Then have a link to your pricing plan below. No need to bother your customer. If they want to buy it, they will. What you have to do is make the use of your app a pleasure, otherwise they'll look elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not fond of the terms "trial version" or "download trial", but I would easily try a "basic free version" (even though it's the same thing), so I've settled on calling my trial version the "free version", with all the obvious feature limitations (trying to set the bar all the way shows "Upgrade to the full version for XXX features"). And it has the full-featured grace-period of "X full-featured [(uses)(days)(hours)] remain" notice. I haven't tested this assumption too thoroughly, but after asking around a bit, most seem to prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be careful with around use limits is this following scenario:

1) User downloads app while researching a problem, tries it briefly, and then moves on.

2) Many months later, user is at last in place to actually seriously try / evaluate the app.  But when they go to try it, the trial has expired, so they move on to try something else.

I've often downloaded apps that "look interesting" when I see them mentioned online, try them briefly to get a sense of them, and then only return to more seriously try them way later when I actually am in need.  I've been burned by the "trial expired" several times, and it has cost some app sellers sales.

A better method is watermarking, if it fits your app.  Or a resettable trial period, maybe allowing two resets of the 30 day trial a year.

It may literally take a year or two before a dabbler is ready to buy, so you want to make sure that your app is positioned to snag that sale when the time comes.