# Keygen and Checker C#?

Tags: key-generator

I am trying to implement a license feature in my software, i want to print the key on the CD and the user have to input the key in the system and the key will be validated then, that means that a key generated in the CD have to produce a value after decryption that will match the hard coded value on the software or something like that.

Can somebody please tell me how to implement this kind of the thing or anything that work with the same i idea.

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to give each customer a unique key or do you want to hand out the same key to all? Either isn't very secure, as billions of warez sites prove. There are some ways to make it more secure if you make them retrieve a key from your homepage. Would you consider such a solution?

Comment: Having a simple serial number system that does not involve online validation etc has advantages, too: Your program will be cracked and distributed on warez sites no matter what you do. If you have a simple serial, they'll just put some serials there people can use. If you have more complex stuff, they are likely to provide downloads including a crack/keygen and your installer - often infected with malware. I'd prefer my program not to be distributed together with malware - many people who crack it, wouldn't buy it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an indirect answer, I'd suggest you start by having a read through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550556/ive-found-my-software-as-cracked-download-on-internet-what-to-do) - it may be that you decide to take another approach to the licensing and protection of your software.

Comment: Actually what i did at first was using MD5 method, but this method requires information to be encrypted like name, company name .....etc. After that i have used RSA which produced a huge output and that didn't work for me plus it needed data to be entered. What i had in mind was something like Windows XP, Whatever serial you put for it if the version was the same it will work. i want something easy to begin with cause i am not that expert in programming yet so that is why i decided to go with this method knowing that is less secure, and yes i want it to be per machine license.